# How to prevent small ISO from marking incorrect size on large target drive?

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, iso-image, dd

I am trying to write a 20GB iso to a 200GB hard disk. However, when I do this, the partition table from the ISO seems to carry the 20GB drive size marking with it, so that KDE Partition Manager thinks the whole drive is 20GB, and will not let me resize the written partitions to use the whole drive unless I create a new partition table (which destroys everything of course). The device properties still show its true size, but the shown unallocated space is incorrectly small.

Comment: Which OS? Information incomplete. I'd suggest to create e.g. Ubuntu installation media (e.g. a USB-stick) and boot it in "Try Ubuntu" mode, then use e.g. "gparted" in there to resize the partition (table).

Comment: One does not usually just "write an ISO" to disk. Are you trying to install an OS or software?

Comment: @Hannu sorry, have clarified.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Indeed. I am jerry rig installing Tiny 11 from a successful VM installation, as booting to the installer on my full machine gives a bogus error about not finding a driver for some media (I confirmed with research that this error can mean just about anything). Thankfully, this seems to be working: Transplanted Tiny 11 did boot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thankfully, I tried using parted (a command line partition manager for Linux), and just running its print command to show the existing partitions made it detect the flaw in the partition table and automatically offer to fix it.

I accepted, then checked in my GUI partition manager (KDE Partition Manager), and it worked!

Answer (score 2):

To the extent that "dd" implies some Linux OS, and "small ISO" really means disk image (an ISO is a CDROM/DVD image, and would not be 20GB)

The solution is to delete the partition and then recreate it with exactly the same starting block and partition type.   Once you have done this, you can then reload the partition into the OS (may require a reboot - sometimes kpartx will do it) and then resize the underlying filesystem.     How you resize the filesystem depends on what the filesystem is - for ext filesystems use resize2fs or resize4fs (same thing, different distro).

Comment: I thought about that, but the selectors for partition sizing aren't very precise in KDE Partition Manager. Thanks for confirming that this would work, though.